# Understanding a stack-use-after-scope error

Tags: c, address-sanitizer

I am working on a multithreaded client using C and the pthreads library, using a boss/worker arch design and am having issues understanding/debugging a stack-use-after-scope error that is causing my client to fail. (I am kinda new to C)

I have tried multiple things, including defining the variable globally, passing a double pointer reference, etc.

```
Boss logic within main:
for (i = 0; i < nrequests; i++)
  {

    struct Request_work_item *request_ctx = malloc(sizeof(*request_ctx));
    request_ctx->server = server;
    request_ctx->port = port;
    request_ctx->nrequests = nrequests;

    req_path = get_path(); //Gets a file path to work on

    request_ctx->path = req_path;

    steque_item work_item = &request_ctx; // steque_item is a void* so passing it a pointer to the Request_work_item

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      while (steque_isempty(&work_queue) == 0) //Wait for the queue to be empty to add more work
      {
        pthread_cond_wait(&c_boss, &mutex);
      }
      steque_enqueue(&work_queue, work_item); //Queue the workItem in a workQueue (type steque_t, can hold any number of steque_items)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&c_worker);
  }

Worker logic inside a defined function:
struct Request_work_item **wi;

  while (1)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      while (steque_isempty(&work_queue) == 1) //Wait for work to be added to the queue
      {
        pthread_cond_wait(&c_worker, &mutex);
      }
      wi = steque_pop(&work_queue); //Pull the steque_item into a Request_work_item type
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&c_boss);

    char *path_to_file = (*wi)->path; //When executing, I get this error in this line: SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope
 ...
 ...
 ...
 continues with additional worker logic
```

I expect the worker to pull the work_item from the queue, dereference the values and then perform some work. However, I keep getting AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope, and the information for this error online is not very abundant so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does this compile without a semicolon after `get_path()`?

Comment: I'll edit it. It does have it in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red flag here is that `&request_ctx` is the address of a local variable. It's not the pointer to the storage allocated with `malloc`, but the address of the variable which holds that storage. That variable is gone once this scope terminates, even though the `malloc`-ed block endures.

Maybe the fix is simply to delete the address-of `&` operator in this line?

```
steque_item work_item = &request_ctx; // steque_item is a void* so passing
                                      // it a pointer to the Request_work_item
```

If we do that, then the comment actually tells the truth. Because otherwise we're making `work_item` a **pointer to a pointer** to the `Request_work_item`.

Since `work_item` has type `void`*, it compiles either way, unfortunately.

If the consumer of the item on the other end of the queue is extracting it as a `Request_work_item *`, then you not only have an access to an object that has gone out of scope, but also a type mismatch even if that object happens to still be in the producer's scope when the consumer uses it. The consumer ends up using a piece of the producer's stack as if it were a `Request_work_item` structure. **Edit:** I see that you are using a pointer-to-pointer when dequeuing the item and accessing it as `(*wi)->path`. Think about changing the design to avoid doing that. Or else, that `wi` pointer has to be dynamically allocated also, and freed. The producer has to do something like:

```
struct Request_work_item **p_request_ctx = malloc(sizeof *p_request_ctx);
struct Request_work_item *request_ctx = malloc(sizeof *request_ctx);

if (p_request_ctx && request_ctx) {
  *p_request_ctx = request_ctx;
   request_ctx->field = init_value;
   // ... etc
   // then p_request_ctx is enqueued.
```

The consumer then has to `free` the structure, and also `free` the pointer. That extra pointer just seems like pure overhead here; it doesn't provide any essential or useful level of indirection.

Comment: Indeed, removing the & from the producer code, and then denormalizing in the consumer to a Request_work_item *wi rather than Request_work_item **wi fixed that problem. Thanks Kaz!